# Is there a way to fill in the gaps of missing/empty data for each of the printed rows to ensure all data is structured similarly?

Tags: python, selenium, csv, web-scraping

Please see the below code that I am using to scrape content from a dynamically generated page and then placing into a CSV. The problem I am running into now is that each "row" could potentially be missing certain elements that I would like to insert as "blank" or some other placeholder so that all of the rows are correctly located under the correct column header when I view this in excel.

```
with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile: 
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile) 
    for heading in All_Heading:
        driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", heading)
        #print("------------- " + heading.text + " -------------")
        ChildElement = heading.find_elements_by_xpath("./../div/div")
        for child in ChildElement:
            driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", child)
            #print(heading.text)
            #print(child.text)
            row = [heading.text, *child.text.split("\n")] # You can also use a tuple here
            print (row)
            csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Is it possible to place the sort of logic I am after in the writer statement or will I need to specifically go after each element I am after to know if it is empty or not? In the end I want each row to contain the same number of elements, even if it means some of them are blank or filler text as this will keep the overall struture of the data intact.

Examples of the output below:

[image: Example output]

As you can see some elements were empty and as such the following elements end up out of line/in the wrong column. (11,12,13,26)

On the same note, is it possible to know extra information about the element I am dealing with in the loop that prints the row? If I knew the class I could then know if its the title, price, weight, brand or so on.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not possible to identify what’s missing from the text itself, at least not reliably since you’d have to search for certain substrings to identify the fields. However if you do have all these values in separate elements under `child`, you can associate each element with its field in two ways assuming there is a class uniquely identifying each field:

1. You can go through all the children using `WebElement. find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//*")`, record what fields are present using `someClass in WebElement.get_attribute("class")`, and later fill in blanks for the missing ones.
2. You can use `WebElement .find_elements()`  (which searches through WebElement's children) and filter by the known class name i.e. `find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=className)`:

```
# ...
fieldClasses = ["Title", "Price", ...] # These are just example classes
for fieldClass in fieldClasses:
    element = child.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=fieldClass)
    row.append(element.text if element else "Blank")
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace empty spaces with some text, before saving the rows.

#### Ex:

```
    row = [heading.text, *child.text.split("\n")] # You can also use a tuplehere
    print (row)
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if len(row[i]) < 1:
            row[i] = "Filler"
    csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you but this did not work for me, the output is the same. I am unsure if its even detecting it as an empty space. I am wondering if the element contains no text if it would even be showing up at this stage.